# ALTER COLUMN IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to alter the table if the table has the column with same data type and number exists

Original tTable structure is

TableName

```
ColumnName NVARCHAR(100)
```

Code for altering column if `ColumnName` with `NVARCHAR` and length 100 exists

```
IF EXISTS(...)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
    ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(200) [NULL|NOT NULL]
END
```

What find query I need to insert at `IF EXISTS(...)`?

Comment: Why you tag 3 `sql-server` versions??? just put the version you are working on !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally always opt for the SQL Server system views rather than the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for reasons [detailed by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views). The added advantage is that in this situation you can exclude computed columns, which just appear as normal columns in the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

```
IF EXISTS
    (   SELECT  1
        FROM    sys.columns c
                INNER JOIN sys.types t
                    ON t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
                    AND t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
        WHERE   c.name = 'ColumnName'
        AND     c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TableName', 'U')
        AND     t.name = 'nvarchar'
        AND     c.max_length = 100
        AND     c.is_computed = 0
    )
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
        ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(200) [NULL|NOT NULL]
    END;
```

As shown in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa15a/4) when using the information schema method you may try and alter a computed column and get an error.

Comment: Agree (+1) regarding the system views, though I prefer the metadata functions for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

Me, I'm way too lazy to type in all those system table joins (let alone the INFORMATION_YADA schema), I just use the metadata functions:

```
IF columnproperty(object_id('dbo.TableName'), 'ColumnName', 'ColumnId') is not null
 and columnproperty(object_id('dbo.TableName'), 'ColumnName', 'Precision') = 200
    ALTER...
```

I believe this works for SQL 2005, but you'll need to check.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I prefer this form as it's a lot easier to figure out what the IF statement is doing...

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
          AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ColumnName' AND DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar'
          AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 100)
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(200) [NULL|NOT NULL]
END
```

Comment: Where you checking length 100 exists??

Comment: well spotted @huMptyduMpty fixed it now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name 'Column Name',
data_type 'Data Type',
CHARacter_maximum_length 'Maximum Length'
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'TableName'
```

from this u get column name and type in form of cursor, consider each row and process rest

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT data_type FROM Information_Schema.Columns WHERE Table_Name = 'MyTable'
      AND Column_Name = 'MyColumn' AND data_type = 'NVARCHAR ' AND character_maximum_length =100)
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]
ALTER COLUMN [ColumnName] NVARCHAR(200) [NULL|NOT NULL]
END
```

Comment: Where you checking `length 100 exists`??

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you try to rename a column that does not exist, PostgreSQL will issue an error. Unfortunately that PostgreSQL does not provide the `IF EXISTS` option for the `RENAME` clause.